# crossfilter.js multidimensional "dimension"

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

not sure how to do this. I have the following data:

Date, Country, QuantityA, QuantityB.

I want to make a timeline Chart with the ratio between Quantity A and B. I also want to create a barChart with Country, which will show the ratio in every country.

The problem is that the ratios are not additive, so if I do this:

```
var timeDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.Date;});
ratioAB     = timeDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return QuantityA/QuantityB}
```

This will return the ratios for every country separately and will add them up. What I want is to add up QuantityA and QuantityB and **then** do the ratio.

Thus, the timeline chart will only show the right ratio if I filter in one of the countries.

Is there a way to add both the country and the date as a dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom grouping to calculate the sum of QuantityA, the sum of QuantityB, and the ratio between the 2. Or you could just create 2 sum groups, one summing QuantityA, the other QuantityB, and then calculate the ratio when you build the visualization.